# Wordpress W3C Validation Error

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, validation

I am trying to run a site through validation on W3C.

This is the error it is providing me with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://run-time.co.za/testing/wp-content/themes/AGLj5/script.js"></script>.
```

You have used character data somewhere it is not permitted to appear.

I understand that the error is the "." after the closing " tag, however I cannot locate that in any of my wordpress code files in order to remove the "."

I have tried searching in the "header.php", "index.php", "page.php", and "single.php", and "home.php" files, but cannot locate it.

If I inspect the element in Google Chrome, it shows that line of code without the "."

but if I inspect the .css file inside the inspect element option in Chrome, then it shows that line as part of the .css but if I look in Wordpress, that line to reference the .js is not there.

Please can someone assist me in finding this line of code in my wordpress files so that I can fix the problem

Thank you

[Website Link](http://www.run-time.co.za/testing)

Comment: How about linking to the site that is a problem?

Comment: [link](http://run-time.co.za/testing)

Comment: Could you comment out that line with the script tag and see if that resolves it?

Comment: @Alex I can't comment it out, as I cannot locate that line in my wordpress files?

Comment: @user1426583 Is it in your header.php file?

Comment: When i open download and open the header.php file on my pc, then that line does appear, and it shows the "."  however it does not show when i edit the file in cPanel?

Comment: I edited the "." out of the file, and replaced header.php with the newly edited copy, however W3C is still picking it up as an error

Comment: @user1426583 I edited the "." out of the file, and replaced header.php with the newly edited copy, however W3C is still picking it up as an error

Comment: @user1426583 There may be some way that you need to reset Wordpress once you have replaced the offending file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22640/discussion-between-user1426583-and-alex-w)